# Jquery changing background of parent div

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following snippet in one of my html pages :

```
<div class="inputboximage">
    <div class="value2">
    <input name='address1'  value='Somewhere' type="text" size="26" maxlength="40" />
    <br />

    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I need the `inputboximage background` to change when I click in the `address1` text field and to revert to the original when it loses focus.

I have used the following :

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("input").focus(function () {
         $(this.parentNode).css('background-image', 'url(images/curvedinputblue.gif)');
    });

    $("input").blur(function () {
    $(this.parentNode).css('background-image', 'url(images/curvedinput.gif)');
    });

  });
  </script>
```

but instead of replacing the image, it seems to be adding a background image to the value2 div as you would expect. I can use `parentNode.parentNode` in this case, but there is also a chance that the `inputboxImage` node could be further up or down the parent tree.

Is there a way I can change this code so that it will navigate down the parent tree until it finds a div called `inputboximage` and replace the image there?

Also, if I have two different div classes, `inputboximage` and `inputboximageLarge`, is there a way to modify this function so that it will work with both, replacing the background image with a different image for each one?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think using

```
$(this).parents('div.inputBoxImage').css(...)
```

instead of `$(this.parentNode)` should work.

See the jQuery [traversing documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parents#expr)

Edit: updated following Prody's answer (changed parent to parents)

Comment: Thanks Phil, this works perfectly.
All I need to do now is figure out how to make it work for other elements which need the same functionality but different background images.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure but I think what you need is what Phill Sacre's answer suggests except using `parents` (notice the last s)

From jQuery API:

parent( String expr ) returns jQuery
Get a set of elements containing the unique parents of the matched set of elements.

parents( String expr ) returns jQuery
Get a set of elements containing the unique ancestors of the matched set of elements (except for the root element).

Comment: You're dead right. parent(...) only searches the immediate parent. I always manage to get those two confused!

Answer (score 0):

Now since in HTML only IDs are unique, you can reference the div directly without doing any traversal:

```
<div class="inputboximage" id="inputboximage">
    <div class="value2">
    <input name='address1'      value='5 The Laurels' type="text" size="26" maxlength="40" />
    <br />

    </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("input").focus(function () {
         $('#inputboximage').css('background-image', 'url(images/curvedinputblue.gif)');
    });


  });
</script>
```

Note that while it is possible to filter the parent elements for CSS classing, using style classes dor behaviour is a Bad Idea TM and you should avoid doing that. But if you are really desperate, you can give it a try:

```
$("input").focus(function () {
         $(this).parents('div.inputboximage').css('background-image', 'url(images/curvedinputblue.gif)');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

.parent().css(changes here)